# Can I host JITSI Meet streaming from own server?

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet, videocall

I'm looking for streaming of audio and Video call using JITSI Meet. But I do not want the streaming server to be hosted on JITSI. Can I host on own server?

Comment: yes, you can host it from your own server. this is what everyone is doing now a days. for running it on your own server, you can follow the jitsi official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can host it on your own server. follow [this](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/intro) guide.

Answer (score 0):

For that thing, you have to set up a Jibri server. After that, you can stream your video and audio into a custom `RTMP` server. The default you can stream into Facebook and Youtube.